# Parse.File returns undefined, trying to save as base64

Tags: javascript, database, parse-platform, base64

One of the fields in a registration form I'm making is to upload an arbitrary text file (.docx, .pdf, etc), which is immediately converted into base64. `$("#form").serialize()` with jQuery is posted to a Node.js route.

On the server side, I'm attempting to create a `Parse.File` object out of that base64 string, like so.

```js
var example_doc = Parse.File(
    file_name,
    { base64: req.body.example_doc }
);

// example_doc === undefined
```

Nothing gets logged or returned from Parse.File, and there is no exception thrown. According to Parse documentation, the only thing required to save a file as a base64 string is to use what I just did. However, it only returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not creating a new instance of Parse.File with `new Parse.File(...)`.